# Getting module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils' has no attribute 'cached_per_instance'

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling

I'm getting AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils' has no attribute 'cached_per_instance' after executing the following code

```
`# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
 
# Initialising the RNN
regressor = Sequential()
 
# Adding the First input hidden layer and the LSTM layer
# return_sequences = True, means the output of every time step to be shared with hidden next layer
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 10, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (TimeSteps, TotalFeatures), return_sequences=True))
 
# Adding the Second Second hidden layer and the LSTM layer
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (TimeSteps, TotalFeatures), return_sequences=True))
 
# Adding the Second Third hidden layer and the LSTM layer
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 5, activation = 'relu', return_sequences=False ))
 
 
# Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))
 
# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
 
##################################################
 
import time
# Measuring the time taken by the model to train
StartTime=time.time()
 
# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 5, epochs = 100)
 
EndTime=time.time()
print("## Total Time Taken: ", round((EndTime-StartTime)/60), 'Minutes ##') `
```

The full error is:

```
` AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-03d3def32698> in <module>
      5 
      6 # Initialising the RNN
----> 7 regressor = Sequential()
      8 
      9 # Adding the First input hidden layer and the LSTM layer

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    242       clz_to_init = []
    243       found_functional_class = False
--> 244       for clz in self.__class__.__bases__:
    245         if issubclass(clz, functional.Functional):
    246           found_functional_class = True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\version_utils.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     63     return super(LayerVersionSelector, cls).__new__(cls)
     64 
---> 65 
     66 class TensorBoardVersionSelector(object):
     67   """Chooses between Keras v1 and v2 TensorBoard callback class."""

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py in <module>
     68 
     69 # pylint: disable=g-classes-have-attributes
---> 70 class Layer(base_layer.Layer):
     71   """Base layer class.
     72 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py in Layer()
   2291 
   2292   @property
-> 2293   @layer_utils.cached_per_instance
   2294   def _call_full_argspec(self):
   2295     # Argspec inspection is expensive and the call spec is used often, so it

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils' has no attribute 'cached_per_instance'
```

`

I first got the cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' error when I was using

from keras.models import Sequential

instead of

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

Now I'm getting the error above
Anybody know a solution?

Comment: pls remove the `'''` at the start and end of your code because it is making all your codes a string and all of them are highlighted as green text. If you meant to format it you should use ( ` ) instead of `'`

Comment: The given code works fine with Tensorflow 2.5.0. There is a issue in older version of Tensorflow and keras compatibility. It is recommended to use Tensorflow latest version i.e., 2.5.0.